# How to model and return hierarchical data with Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, tree, cypher, hierarchical-data

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298659/how-to-generate-hierarchical-json-data-with-microdoft-sql-server-2016) about returning a hierarchical/tree data structure with SQL Server 2016.

I would like to know how can I do the same with Neo4j cypher query?

This is the data that currently exists that follows the adjacent list format. All the Persons have an Id called **PersonId**. The person's father points to another person who's id is **FatherId**.

```
    PersonId    FatherId    Name
    1           NULL        4th Grand Father
    2           1           3rd Grand Father
    3           2           2nd Grand Father
    4           3           Grand Father
    5           4           Father
    6           4           Uncle
    7           6           Cousin
    8           5           Brother
    9           5           Me
```

The JSON data has to be returned in this format:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "4th Grand Father",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Name": "3rd Grand Father",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Name": "2nd Grand Father",
            "Children": [
              {
                "Name": "Grand Father",
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "Name": "Father",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "Name": "Brother"
                      },
                      {
                        "Name": "Me"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Uncle",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "Name": "Cousin"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by the format. 3rd Grand Father isn't nested in 4th Grand Father (except the name) and likewise with 2nd Grand Father within 3rd Grand Father, but Grand Father is nested in 2nd Grand Father and so are its children. Why are some of these nested and others aren't?

Comment: I clarified what is **PersonId** and **FatherId** in the question itself.

Comment: Still confused, I still don't understand the nesting, in that 4th, 3rd, and 2nd Grand Fathers are at the same depth in the JSON, not hierarchically nested, but Grand Father, Father, Brother, Me, Uncle, and Cousin are all hierarchically nested. The nesting strategy isn't consistent here, and that makes it hard to come up with a general solution.

Comment: I corrected the hierarchy now.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not a direct answer to your question -- As a place to start, you might look at Rik Van Bruggen's blog post on graphs for family relationships: http://blog.bruggen.com/2014/01/leftovers-from-holidays-genealogy-graphs.html?q=family&view=magazine

I understand that you want this particular format, but it wouldn't deal very well with more complex kinds of relationships or answers.