# Convert Json Object To SQL Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, json, query-builder

I want to generate sql query dynamically. I found this tool

```
  http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html
```

And i have the following JSON object:

```
{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "name",
      "field": "name",
      "type": "string",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "zura"
    },
    {
      "condition": "OR",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "category",
          "field": "category",
          "type": "integer",
          "input": "select",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "price",
          "field": "price",
          "type": "double",
          "input": "number",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "123"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "in_stock",
      "field": "in_stock",
      "type": "integer",
      "input": "radio",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "condition": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "category",
          "field": "category",
          "type": "integer",
          "input": "select",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "in_stock",
          "field": "in_stock",
          "type": "integer",
          "input": "radio",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i want to generate SQL Table in order to save this JSON data properly. 
Is there any way to generate Table, if yes please give me link or please help me to create same table

Comment: I don't see how the key values would translate to SQL datatypes, ie, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, etc (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp). You could use the `CREATE TABLE` statement (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp), but based on your JSON values, I don't think you'd be creating a valid SQL table. For example, from your data: `rules["type"] = string`, `string` is not a valid SQL datatype, whereas `VARCHAR(200)` is. If you were to dynamically generate your table based on an object, I'd presume you'd need the right datatypes, at the very least, as key values.

Comment: Data type does not meter, first i need just Table(May Be tables) structure to save my JSON data. I can change data type in table any time.

Comment: In order to build the structure of an SQL table, you first have to `CREATE TABLE` (see link in my last comment). When you create the table, you have to define its structure, which requires defining a data type. IE, the SQL table has to know what type of data to expect (numbers, text, etc). As far as I know, you can't create an SQL table without setting data types for the properties you are trying to capture. It's a requirement when the table is created. A lot of people use MySQL Workbench to draft up their vision and the program spits out the SQL table for them.

Comment: I know how to create TABLE sql, but i do not know how to create TABLE structure to save my JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Json data needs to be decoded using recursive SQL‌ function.You first need to create a self-referenced table like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE jsonCondition(
ConditionId INT IDENTITY,
ParentCondotionId INT ,
Id NVARCHAR(20),
Field NVARCHAR(20),
Type NVARCHAR(20),
Input NVARCHAR(20),
Operator NVARCHAR(20),
Value NVARCHAR(20) 
)
```

then please refer to my other json recursive Conversion to SQL at:
[How to generate hierarchical JSON data with Microsoft SQL Server 2016?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298659/how-to-generate-hierarchical-json-data-with-microsoft-sql-server-2016/41823306#41823306)